# Join on Id in Variant (Array) Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables t1 and t2 created as follows:

**Create Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
    id integer AUTOINCREMENT START 1 INCREMENT 1,
    name varchar(10) DEFAULT RANDSTR(10, random()),
    id_array variant,
) 

CREATE TABLE t2(
    id integer AUTOINCREMENT START 1 INCREMENT 1,
    name varchar(10) DEFAULT RANDSTR(10, random())
)
```

**Goal**

I am looking to join t2 to t1 if the id of the record exists in the t1 variant array.

**What I've Tried**

I came across the ARRAY_CONTAINS function which looked perfect. But with the following I am receiving no results:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.name
FROM t1, t2 
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(t1.id_array, array_construct(t2.id))
```

**How Do I Get This?**

Any suggestions on how to achieve the following result?

```
t1 record: 
{id: 1, name: 'A-123', ids_array: '["1", "2"]'}

t2 records:
{id: 1, name: 'test'},
{id: 2, name: 'test2'}
```

**Desired Result**

```
{id: 1, name: 'A-123', joined_name: 'test'},

{id: 1, name: 'A-123', joined_name: 'test2'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to debug what's happening I added more and more line to the below SQL, but the short story is you have the parameters to [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_contains.html) back to front:

```
WITH t1(id, name, ids_array) AS (
    SELECT column1, column2, SPLIT(column3,',') FROM VALUES
        (1, 'A-123', '1,2')
), t2(id, name) AS (
    SELECT column1, column2 FROM VALUES
        (1, 'test'),     
        (2, 'test2')
)
SELECT t1.id
    ,t2.name
    ,t2.id
    ,t1.ids_array
    ,ARRAY_CONTAINS('1'::variant, t1.ids_array) as const_1
    ,ARRAY_CONTAINS('2'::variant, t1.ids_array) as const_2
    ,t2.id::text::variant as v1
    ,ARRAY_CONTAINS(v1, t1.ids_array) as it_works
FROM t1, t2
```

gives:

| ID | NAME | ID | IDS_ARRAY | CONST_1 | CONST_2 | V1 | IT_WORKS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | 1 | [ "1", "2" ] | TRUE | TRUE | "1" | TRUE |
| 1 | test2 | 2 | [ "1", "2" ] | TRUE | TRUE | "2" | TRUE |

so now using the correct form:

```
WITH t1(id, name, ids_array) AS (
    SELECT column1, column2, SPLIT(column3,',') FROM VALUES
        (1, 'A-123', '1,2')
), t2(id, name) AS (
    SELECT column1, column2 FROM VALUES
        (1, 'test'),     
        (2, 'test2')
)
SELECT t1.id
    ,t2.name
FROM t1, t2 
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(t2.id::text::variant, t1.ids_array)
```

we get:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test |
| 1 | test2 |

Answer (score 2):

[ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_contains.html#array-contains) expects the following parameters: variant and array:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.name
FROM t1, t2 
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(t1.id_array, array_construct(t2.id))
```

should be rather:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.name
FROM t1
JOIN t2 
  ON ARRAY_CONTAINS(t2.id::variant, t1.id_array)
```

Comment: Interestingly enough this still returns no rows. Do you think the fact that the ids in the id_array are enclosed in double quotes might effect anything? e.g. [ "1", "4" ]